# How to use Dodge and Parry in M&M3e and DC Adventures?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I know that Dodge is to defend against range attacks and Parry is for defending against melee attacks. I also know that when calculating your Dodge or Parry DC to defend you are supposed to add 10 to the base number.

What isn't clear is if there is any instance when the base Dodge/Parry number is used ***without*** adding 10 to calculate a DC. Basically, is there any reason not to just write the Dodge/Parry value on my character sheet with the 10 already added in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Resistance Checks](http://www.d20herosrd.com/#TOC-RESISTANCE-CHECKS)

As mentioned in the SRD, Resistance checks are sometimes called for to nullify or dampen the effects of incoming powers. Dodge is one of the common checks made, with the formula d20 + defense bonus + modifiers, vs. hazard DC.

In fact, [the Defense class is considered the equivalent of a Routine check](http://www.d20herosrd.com/3-abilities#TOC-DEFENSE-CLASS) for the corresponding Defense, hence the +10 used in the formula.

## [Defend Action](http://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure#TOC-DEFEND-STANDARD-ACTION)

By using your standard action for the round, you can adopt a defensive stance. You get to roll a Defense check against every incoming attack. You also get to add 10 to any roll that comes up as 10 or less, so each roll  is guaranteed to be at least +11 (so it's always a net gain compared to "passive" defense).

Comment: So if the Dodge/Parry+10 is just a routine check, would rolling a d20 and adding the Dodge/Parry when being attacked be a legal move? According to the DC book I have it seems you roll the attack against the Dodge/Parry DC. But when you describe it as a routine check it makes me wonder if at the very least it wouldnt make for a more fun house rule, if not actually a legal move for both the pc and the dm to be rolling for defense and attack?

Comment: Well, there's nothing in RAW that supports it. The main advantage behind Defense Class being 10 + skill is that it makes for less rolls. If you think doubling the number of rolls made in an attack makes for more fun gameplay, you're welcome to try, but I have a hunch that it will only bog the game down.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. There's a case when you can make a roll : when you use the Defend action. See http://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure#TOC-DEFEND-STANDARD-ACTION . It does take up your standard action for the round, though, so you don't get to attack.